# Finding the shift of a vector which minimizes the difference to another vector

Tags: matlab, fminsearch

I am very sorry if similar question was asked before. I have two vectors of *50 x n*, and want to find the shift of the first vector, which provides the closest match with the second vector. I have tried `fminsearch` and `circshift` in Matlab, however, could not exactly find how to use them in this case.

I also saw the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13563453/finding-the-best-scale-shift-between-two-vectors), however, I do not need a representative function or interpolation to match the two vectors. Instead, I just want the best shift of one profile, which minimizes the differences along the profile. I will be happy if you can direct me. Also, could I use `fminsearch` to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you familiar with the notions `correlation` and `convolution`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it as follows with [**`gallery`**](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gallery.html#zmw57dd0e261757)'s circulant matrix:

```
%// example data
A = randi([1,10],[1,10])
B = circshift(A,[0,3])
```

With this data the matching shift is expected to be **3**

```
[~,minidx] = min(sum(abs(bsxfun(@minus,A,gallery('circul',B))),2))
shift = numel(A) - minidx + 1

shift =

     3
```

---

### Explanation

```
%// circulant matrix 
circul = gallery('circul',B)
%// substract vector A from all shifted rows of circulant matrix
diffs = bsxfun(@minus,A,circul)
%// sum absolute differences
C = sum(abs(diffs),2)
%// find index of row with minimum difference
[~,minidx] = min(C)
%// depending on your defintion of "shift", means
%// depending on where you start to count, you may want to
%// change this:
shift = numel(A) - minidx + 1
```

---

### Things to consider

This is a kind of brute-force method, vectorized and efficient though. But it **analyzes all possible shifts** which could occur to vector B. If you have really long vectors (numel > 10000+) you could run into memory problems where a `fminsearch` wouldn't. On the other hand you can never be sure `fminsearch` would find the best solution, unless your data follows a clear pattern or you analyze all shifts anyway, but then it's gonna be slow as well.

Comment: Thank you very much for very well explanation! That's a very efficient way and worked quite well! I have 2 temperature profiles (each having dimensions of maximum 300 x 1), and have the exact vertical coordinates for the second profile, however, the vertical coordinates of the first profile is not clear. I would like to find these vertical coordinates (in sub-mm scale), which best match these two profiles (e.g. with an upper bound). Which function would work for this case?  I thought of finding two equations (as suggested below) which match two profiles, but I am not sure to where I can reach.

Comment: @Tethus So you mean the "real" shift is not an integer? Then I would take the rows returned by the above function and the ones below and above, interpolate and repeat the procedure.

Comment: @ thewaywewalk that worked well. Thanks again for your input and the idea!

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this just OLS?  To clarify, I assume the second matrix is Y and the first matrix is X, both have dimension `50 x n` for some pre-specified value for `n`.  For simplicity, stack the matrix, so that `X` and `Y` are `(50 x n) x 1` (`50xn` rows and `1` column.  Then your model is

```
Y_i = a + bX_i + e_i.
```

Your goal is to minimize the sum of squared errors:

```
min_{a,b} sum_i e_i^2.
```

You can either use fmincon or solve for the analytical solution.  See simple linear regression for formulas:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression